# Elasticsearch MatchQuery is returning wrong results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-7

I am using a `matchQuery` to query Elasticsearch in Java. Below is my query:

`sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("TransactionId_s","BulkRunTest.20Nov20201446.00"));`

The field `TransactionId_s` is not a `keyword`. And I am expecting the matchQuery to match the exact string I have given and return the results. There should be no documents in Elasticsearch with `TransactionId_s` as `BulkRunTest.20Nov20201446.00`. But I am getting some results and they have the `TransactionId_s` like below:

```
"TransactionId_s" : "BulkRunTest.17Sep20201222.00"
"TransactionId_s" : "BulkRunTest.22Sep20201450.00"
"TransactionId_s" : "BulkRunTest.20Sep20201250.00"
```

When I tried using a `termQuery` instead of `matchQuery`, I am getting 0 results, which is the expected result. I thought `matchQuery` would allow me to query any field for the given value without me having to worry about tokenization. Am i wrong? And how do I resolve the issue I am seeing?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Match` queries are analyzed ie it applied the same analyzer which is used on the field at index time, you can [analyzer API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) and see the tokens for indexed and search term.

Considering you have a `text` field with default analyzer(Standard) it will generate the below token for search term `BulkRunTest.20Nov20201446.00`

```
POST /_analyze
{
    "analyzer" : "standard",
    "text" : "BulkRunTest.20nov20201446.00"
}
```

And generated tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "bulkruntest", // notice this token
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "20nov20201446.00",
            "start_offset": 12,
            "end_offset": 28,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Now lets see the tokens for one of the matches doc `BulkRunTest.17Sep20201222.00`

```
POST /_analyze
{
    "analyzer" : "standard",
    "text" : "BulkRunTest.17Sep20201222.00"
}
```

**And generated tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "bulkruntest", // notice same token 
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "17sep20201222.00",
            "start_offset": 12,
            "end_offset": 28,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**As you can see `bulkruntest` is the same token in both indexed and search term, hence the match query returned the search result and same is with another indexed doc.**

If you used the default auto-generated mapping and have `.keyword` subfield then you can use the `.keyword` field for the exact search.

**Working example**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {   // term query
      "TransactionId_s.keyword": {   // .keyword subfield is used
        "value": "BulkRunTest.20Nov20201446.00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_in",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "TransactionId_s": "BulkRunTest.20Nov20201446.00"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly detailed answer! I ended up defining the field as a keyword and now it works as expected.